# VBA Coding in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm very new to VBA coding, and I'm having a few hiccups with my understanding. At the moment, I'm looking to find out how to write a code that puts a motion path outside of the main sequence on the animation pane. It's for coding the motion path of a ball image to the left.

The following bit of code is what I'm trying to use.

```
    Set effNew = ActivePresentation.Slides(18).TimeLine.MainSequence _
          .AddEffect(Shape:=Picture2, effectId:=msoAnimEffectCustom, _
          Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
```

I've tried replacing the "Timeline.MainSequence" with "Timeline.InteractiveSequences" but there's been no progress.

Comment: Always helps to mention what is happening (or not happening) when you run your code, and exactly how that's different from what you expect/want.  "no progress" doesn't tell us much about that.

Comment: There is an arrow shape that I've manually tied to the macro I wrote. Upon playing the slide in presentation mode, the ball moves before I even click the button. Once I click the arrow, it resets the slide to the beginning, and it generates a new animation in the animation pane.

Comment: Your post doesn't mention any button - is the code you posted triggered by the button?

Comment: The code I posted is meant to be triggered when an arrow/button is clicked to enact a motion path on Picture 2.

Comment: Do you remove the effect after it's completed?  Not that familiar with PPT animation but does it persist between sessions?

Comment: It stays until I click the button, and then the slide resets to the beginning, and the appearance effect re-triggers.